# ocr api for image of a webcam

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Is there any java ocr api that can detect text from non scanned image of a webcam. I used tess4j .It can detect text from scanned image. But it can not detect text from non scanned image such as image of a webbcam.

Comment: how is it that you suppose that a webcam image differs from a scanned image?

Comment: I am not sure . I tried them both. tess4j can't detect text from webcam image

Comment: You probably will have to process the webcam images before OCR. It may include rescale, threshold, denoise, sharpen, etc.

Comment: Text extraction from images is not a trivial subject, and per the answer below, APIs are typically tuned to expect a certain image quality input. Finding an API that handles a variety of inputs will allow you to try each algorithm to find the one that best handles your use case and input source. Webcams are typically low resolution video cameras, and grabbing an image from a video frame does not always result in images of sufficient quality to allow processing, particularly if the text is not sharp.